# Why we need to install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am new to django and I have heard of virualenv and virtualenvwrapper but don't understand why they are required. I am also confused that when we install any package how how it maps to the environment. Please also tell me where to put our project apps, can we put it anywhere irrespective of virtualenv folder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: might help: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/django-in-a-virtualenv/

Comment: I can't believe I'm actually going to comment on this, but it kinda seems logical that you would need the virtualenv, then the wrapper, then Django... right?

Comment: Ok thanks, Also plz tell me where to start my app inside virtual env folder or any.

Comment: Your Django app doesn't need to live in the virtualenv, it can literally exist anywhere on the drive.

Comment: then what defines the mapping between virtual env and our django project. ie how it relates to each other.

Comment: Ok i got your answer ie what ever i will install using pip will go to virtual env. but what in case we have multiple virtual envs.

Comment: Whichever virtualenv is `active` when you run `pip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the comments and answers I came to conclution that-
At first we have to install virtual environment to isolate my project settings from system's settings. Here settings refer to Various packages with different versions. This isolation helps to prevent any conflict between systems setting and projects settings. Also there can be multiple projects.

---

Now secondly we need to install virtualenvwrapper because there may be many virtualenvs in my PC ie. one with python3 other with python2 as required in different projects, So we need a wrapper where we can put all our envs and manage them.(Installing virtualenvwrapper is optional, virtualenv will provide all the necessary commands to us).

---

At last as you have virtualenv installed you can now activate the virtualenv and then install Django, pip will automatically link Django with activated env. You can put your project in any directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Python 2.7.5 (As per the system requirement, according to this machine, it is a 32Bit windows 7 machine) link: http://www.python.org/getit/ **(Ignore if you're on OS X or Linux)**
2. Install Python **(Ignore if you're on OS X or Linux)**
3. Now goto My Computer Properties > Advance System Settings > Environment Variables > inside “System Variables” scroll for “Path” and click edit, now add the path “C:\Python27;”. **(Ignore if you're on OS X or Linux)**
4. To check whether the path is edited correctly, goto cmd and type “Python” and it will redirect to python.
5. Now goto “http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py” and save it as ez_setup.py to a directory
6. Open command prompt and navigate to the directory where ez_setup.py is saved and run the following command: “python ez_setup.py”, once it is installed successfully , (make sure during this process the machine should be connected to the internet)
7. Step 6 will install easy_setup inside python27/scripts folder
8. Goto C:\python27\scripts and type “easy_install pip” or in Mac type easy_install
9. Now to install django, type “pip install django”

for virtual env, you can download and install django toolbelt, and then u can use the command

```
virtualenv venv
```

it will install everything for u, then use this

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

now whatever u will install using pip, it will goto virtual envoirnment u just created,